# Create custom validators for dynamic forms angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I just red angular 2 cookbook in how you I can create dynamic forms but I wander how I can add custom validators to particular field.

```
questions.forEach(question => {
  group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
                                          : new FormControl(question.value || '');
});
```

Here they  form a from group to hold form inputs so what about if I want to apply a particular validation to a particular question 
Ex: if I has input for confirming password matching. 
I know that there is `validateequal` attribute to do this task how I can apply this `validateequal` or even create my own custom validation

**Note**  that it is dynamic form which means could hold any input  for example i am planning to use the same form to generate log in form which means that it only has password input , i need away to check if there is input will hold password and if any will hold password confirmation and if so then i need to check if they are matching before submit

Comment: this should help ya out mate. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2

As far as custom validations go, im in the same boat trying to figure that out. I believe custom directives will be the way to go, but I could be wrong. 

This one might help you out too, a little dated, but you can get an idea from it. http://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/

Comment: i red all these articles but my problem is i am building form dynamically and i want to verify confirm password input but actually at this moment password control has not built yet. @Swank do you know any way i can set form validation manually

Comment: @kero did you got it?

Comment: @kero did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alrighty, I think I have it.

You're going to use custom directives in order to get the Job done.

Here is a very rudimentary tutorial on custom directives https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

if you create that however you're templating your app, you can easily modify it to fit your parameters.

in mine, i've used that example in the following way.

*Your NgModule || app.module.ts*

```
import { customDirective } from '../directive/path';
```

*Your customDirective.ts || js*

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
   selector: '[fooSelector]'
})

export class CustomDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}
  @Input('fooSelector') testing: Object;

  //this controls event type with change being the event
  @HostListener('change') onChange(){
    this.logicFunct(this.htmlAttr); //will define htmlAttr in template
  }

  //this is the validator logic
  private logicFunct($obj: Object){
    // submit logic here - for ex:
    if($obj != 'test) {
      this.varBar = true; //check template ngIf
    }
  }
}
```

*Your Template*

```
<input
  type="text"
  #htmlAttr
  [fooSelector]="this.htmlAttr._value"
  *ngIf="!this.varBar">
</input>
```

I'm almost positive there are other *better* ways to do this, and if someone has one, please let us know!

Hope this helps anyone stumbling upon it.

Comment: thanks for you contributing i really appreciate that , but my problem is completely different,

Comment: well, it is and it isn't. Although this is a bit unorthodox, you can use this approach for your custom validations.

Comment: my actual problem that i need away to grab value from another input if this input field exists, check  above my update to question